# Try to connect Mysql but FAILED

Tags: c++, mysql

I tried to connect MySQL.
But it seems like something goes wrong and I cannot get it.
I'm basically sending a simple `SELECT` statement to the database and checking if the operation was successful or not.

Unfortunately, this always outputs *"Failed!"*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char *db = "test";
    const char *server = "localhost";
    const char *user = "root";
    const char *password = "111222";
    int port = 3306;

    const char *sql = "select 1";

    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
    // con = mysql_init(con);

    if (con == NULL) {
        cout << "Error:" << mysql_error(con) << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    MYSQL *new_con = mysql_real_connect(con, server, user, password, db, port, NULL, 0);

    if (new_con != NULL) {
        cout << "Successful!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Failed!" << mysql_error(new_con) << endl;
    }

    int ret = mysql_query(new_con, sql);

    if (ret != 0) {
        cout << "error: " << mysql_error(new_con) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you connect with that credentials ? `mysql --user=root --password=111222 test`

Comment: Also don't put images in your question. Edit the question and paste your C++ code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! `mysql --user=root --password=111222 test` works well. But when I used my cpp code to connect MySQL, it failed.

Comment: What is `mysql_error(con)` returning?

Comment: Nothing. The complet output is
`Failed!` and 
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
I think the connection is not completed and `Segmentation fault` is because **new_con** is **NULL**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html

```
MYSQL mysql;

mysql_init(&mysql);
if (!mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","root","111222","test",0,NULL,0))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to database: Error: %s\n",
          mysql_error(&mysql));
}
else {
    cout << "Successfully connected." << endl;
}
```

What does this sample code print ?

Comment: The output is `Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: I reinstalled MySQL. I think it is the version problem. Thanks.

Comment: It's probably because it was configured to listen on a file socket and not on TCP/IP.

Comment: But I think it is different during connection with db. Remote connection is based on TCP/IP. Local connection is based on socket. I'm not sure but I remember I have seen that before.